# Trouble with guessing game

Tags: c++, if-statement, random

I need to do a Guessing game where the program generates a random number and the user has to guess the number. If the user guesses the number in less than 10 guesses the program congratulates them and lets them know they were under 10 guesses. If they were above 10 guesses then it lets them know it was above 10, etc.

The problem I'm facing is if, for example, the user guesses the number in 3 tries and then decides to play again with a whole new other number, and this time guesses it in 8 tries, instead of still congratulating them because it was under 10 tries, it counts the 3 tries from the previous game. This then leads the program to tell them they were over 10 tries, even though they were not. I don't know how to fix this. The code I've done so far is as follows:

```
int main()
{
   srand(time(0));
   int guess;
   int number;
   char selection = 'y';
   int numberOfGuesses=0;

 while(selection == 'y' || selection == 'Y')
 {
      number = rand() % 1000 + 1;

      cout << "I have a number between 1 and 1000.\nCan you guess my number?\nPlease type your first guess: ";
      cin >>guess;

      do
      {
         if(number > guess)
         {
            cout << "Too low. Try again: " << endl;
            cin >> guess;
            numberOfGuesses++;
         }
         if (number < guess)
         {
            cout << "Too high. Try again: " << endl;
            cin >> guess;
            numberOfGuesses++;
         }

      } 

      while(number != guess);

      if(numberOfGuesses < 9)
      {
            cout << "You guessed the number in less than 10 guesses!\n Would you like to play again (y or n)?";
            cin >> selection;
      }
      else if(numberOfGuesses > 9)
      {
            cout << "You guessed the number\n Would you like to play again (y or n)?";
            cin >> selection;
      }

      else if(numberOfGuesses == 9)
      {
            cout << "You guessed the number.\n Would you like to play again (y or n)?";
            cin >> selection;
      }

  }

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Where is `numberOfGuesses` being cleared to zero?

Comment: You could use `else if (numberOfGuesses >= 9)` to get rid of some code duplication.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are not resetting the counter.
Just put `int numberOfGuesses=0;` within the `while` loop:

```
while(selection == 'y' || selection == 'Y')
{
    int numberOfGuesses=0;
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `numberOfGuesses` to 0 before every game. Your program only sets it once when the program first launched.

Answer (score 0):

You are not resetting `numberOfGuesses` to zero after each round. You can solve the problem using one of couple of methods.

1. Reset the value of `numberOfGuesses` to zero at the end of the first `while` loop.

   ```
   while(selection == 'y' || selection == 'Y')
   {
      ...
      numberOfGuesses = 0;
   }
   ```
2. Don't define the variable until the start of that `while` loop. Define it as the first statement and initialize it zero.

   ```
   while(selection == 'y' || selection == 'Y')
   {
      int numberOfGuesses = 0;
      ...
   }
   ```